# Javascript Error: Uncaught ReferenceError: [function] is not defined

Tags: javascript

I have two js files, both called by one HTML file.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/levelmovement.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/generation.js"></script>
```

Part of levelmovement.js :

```
function moveLevel(){
    if(firstreset == true){
        resetTime();
    }
    var time2 = new Date();
    var millis2 = time2.getTime();
    var millis3 = millis2 - millis1;
    poschange = Math.floor(millis3 / 5);
    for(i = 0; i < chunkpos.length; i++){
        temppos[i] = chunkpos[i] - poschange;
        if(temppos[i] <= -150){
            temppos[i] += 1200;
            generate(i);
        }
        pos = temppos[i];
        document.getElementById('chunk' + i).setAttribute('style','left: ' + pos + 'px;');
    }
}
```

The function "moveLevel()" is called like this:

```
window.onload = function(){
    gameLoop();
}

function gameLoop(){
    if(currentscreen == 'playing'){
        moveLevel();
    }
    setTimeout('gameLoop()',1);
}
```

The entire generation.js :

```
var generatedtop;
var howtogentop = 'gen';
var howtogenbottom = 'gen';
var chunktogenerate = 0;

function topGen(g){
    document.getElementById('t' + chunktogenerate).setAttribute('src','images/terrain/t' + g + '.png');
    if(g == 'gap0'){
        howtogentop = 'gap';
    }
    else{
        howtogentop = 'gen';
    }

    if(g == 'gap0' || g == 'gap2'){
        generatedtop = 'gap';
    }
    else{
        generatedtop = 'default';
    }
}

function bottomGen(g){
    document.getElementById('b' + chunktogenerate).setAttribute('src','images/terrain/b' + g + '.png');
    if(g == 'gap0'){
        howtogenbottom = 'gap';
    }
    else{
        howtogenbottom = 'gen';
    }
}

function generate(chunknum){
    chunktogenerate = chunknum;
    var rand1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*100)+1;
    var rand2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*100)+1;
    if(howtogentop == 'gen'){
        if(rand1 <= 25){
            topGen('space');
        }
        if(rand1 <= 50 && rand1 > 25){
            topGen('jump');
        }
        if(rand1 <= 75 && rand1 > 50){
            topGen('slide');
        }
        if(rand1 > 75){
            topGen('gap0');
        }
    }
    if(howtogentop == 'gap'){
        topGen('gap2');
    }

    if(howtogenbottom == 'gen'){
        if(generatedtop == 'gap'){
            if(rand2 <= 33){
                bottomGen('space');
            }
            if(rand2 <= 66 && rand2 > 66){
                bottomGen('jump');
            }
            if(rand2 > 66){
                bottomGen('gap0');
            }
        }
        if generatedtop != 'gap'){
            if(rand2 <= 25){
                bottomGen('space');
            }
            if(rand2 <= 50 && rand2 > 25){
                bottomGen('jump');
            }
            if(rand2 <= 75 && rand2 > 50){
                bottomGen('jump');
            }
            if(rand2 > 75){
                bottomGen('gap0');
            }
        }
    }
    if(howtogenbottom == 'gap'){
        bottomGen('gap2');
    }
}
```

I have checked over everything and "moveLevel()" only works if i remove this line of code:

```
generate(i);
```

It appears as if the browser cannot see the "generate()" function and I don't know why...

Comment: Try to put the `generation.js` script tag before the `levelmovement.js` script tag

Comment: @MarkLinus that didnt work. :(

Comment: Then see if you are calling an inexistent function inside the `generate` function

Comment: I just hope its not a typo...

Comment: @MarkLinus I checked... i am only calling 2 functions, both defined in generate.js.

Comment: below the question's tags (javascript web-development), there's a `close` link

Comment: @MarkLinus I don't see one, but I marked toggled the checkmark next to your answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line:

```
if generatedtop != 'gap'){
```

is missing a bracket. The correct is:

```
if(generatedtop != 'gap'){
```

Comment: THANK YOU! Your a lifesaver! (And darn it was a typo...)
It works now. :)

Answer (score 3):

I came to this page searching for a solution to a similar issue I had. Although this page did not help directly but gave a direction to fix the problem.

**Here is the actual reason why this happens:**

When you have a function in a js file say file1.js, that you are calling in another js file say file2.js, even though they are called on the same html page, the function will not work **if there is any js error** in the whole file1.js, its like **the whole js file is not included at all if it has an error**.

So the solution is to clean up all the js errors that you are getting in all the included js files.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

That's because your calling the function before it is defined. Changing the order of loading your js files should fix the issue.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/generation.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/levelmovement.js"></script>
```

Comment: but every function in my "game" only runs with window.onload or after that